# How can I delete the empty lines that appear on my python output?

Tags: python

I keep getting blank lines [image: 1] when executing my code, I'm using a for loop to create this pattern [image: 2], but i need to get rid of the spaces between the printed lines.

This is the code im using

```
n = int(input())
a = "_"
b = "|"
for i in range(0,n,1):
    if i == 0:
        print(" " * (2*n - 1) + "_*_")
        print(" " * 2*((n - 1)) + b + " " * 3 + b)
    else:
        print(" " * ((2*n - 1) - 2*i) + a + (" " * ((i + 1) * 4 - 3) ) + a)
        print(" " * ((2*(n-1)) - 2*i)  + b + (" " * ((i + 1)*4 - 1)) + b)
```

Comment: Also show what it is currently printing and what you would like it to look like

Comment: you should print `_|   |_` in a line.

Answer (score 1):

Lets break this down a bit and come up with some equations. First lets examine a possible output to see what the padding needs to be on the outer and inner parts of the pyramid.

```
       _*_         n=5, i=0, outer=7, inner=0
     _|   |_       n=5, i=1, outer=5, inner=3
   _|       |_     n=5, i=2, outer=3, inner=7
 _|           |_   n=5, i=3, outer=1, inner=11
|               |  n=5, i=4, outer=0, inner=15
```

For the inner, if `i == 0` then `inner = 0` otherwise `inner = (4 * i) - 1`

For the outer, if `n - i == 1` then `outer = 0` otherwise `outer = (2 * (n - i - 1)) - 1`

Now we can code this together:

```
for i in range(n):
    outer = " " * ((2 * (n - i - 1)) - 1)
    inner = " " * ((4 * i) - 1)

    if i == 0:
        # inner is 0
        print(outer + "_*_")
    elif n - i == 1:
        # outer is 0
        print("|" + inner + "|")
    else:
        print(outer + "_|" + inner + "|_")
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to flakes' answer, this is because the print() prints on a new line. This is why there is a space : instead of being on the same line, both caracters are on a separate line. As such, you should have a and b in the same print statement as shown by flakes